# Get filename and time of VLC's currently playing file

Tags: video, vim, vlc-media-player

I am starting a project where I need to analyze some video. I want to write my notes in vim and read in an external command so I can quickly anchor my notes to a particular video segment. Say I was looking at the video file `video.mp4` and `50000ms` into the video something interesting happened.

```
Something interesting happened | video.mp4 50000ms.
```

Is there a way using VLC's command line (`vlc`) or web interface (through `curl`) to get the filename and time (current position in milliseconds) of the file that is currently playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for this as well, and stumbled upon the [autohotkey plugin for vlc](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/83886-vlc-http-2-interface-library-for-lastest-vlc-media-player/). There I saw that there is also an xml for the current state:

`http://localhost:8080/requests/status.xml`

It contains the filename and time/length amongst other infos. Check the plugin for some more ideas, I could not find a documentation for the status.xml.